# Mongoose - query to get data from multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to ***get query of the mongoose*** in nodejs application as describe below out put.
user.js, comment.js and post.js are the model files I used.

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;  

var userSchema = new Schema({  
        nick_name:{type:String},  
        email: {  
            type: String,  
            trim: true,  
            required: '{PATH} is required!',
            index: true,
        },     
    },{ collection: 'user'});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**comment.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var commentSchema = new Schema({  
         comment: type:String,  
         user_id:{
            type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'
         },  
         is_active :1
},{ collection: 'comment'});
```

**post.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var postSchema = new Schema({
        post: type:String,
        user_id:{
           type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'
        },
        is_active :1
},{ collection: 'post'});
```

**wants to get out put as follows:**

```
{
 "nick_name":"prakash",
 "email":"prakash@mailinator.com",
 "comments":[
      {
      "comment":"this is a comment text1",
      "is_active":1,
      },
      {
      "comment":"this is a comment text2",
      "is_active":1,
      }
 ],
 "posts":[
      {
      "post":"this is a post text1",
      "is_active":1,
      },
      {
      "post":"this is a post text2",
      "is_active":1,
      },
      {
      "post":"this is a post text3",
      "is_active":1,
      },
 ]
}
```

**dependencies**

```
"express"  => "version": "4.7.4",
"mongoose" => "version": "4.4.5",
"mongodb"  => "version": "2.4.9",
"OS"  => "ubuntu 14.04 lts 32bit",
```

if query is not possible ,please suggests me a proper mongoose plugn.
but I don't want to any changes in user.js file and its userSchema object.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - haha Simplez...

Comment: I am also struggeling now, I have comment object, Like object, and other object. and I want to show User profile Page with all the activities that he does.  but the point is they  are different collection.  and If I do separately then they will not be ordered by time

Comment: I do see the humor in 'query of mongoose', but props to @laxman, I'm only fluent in one language.  To phrase this in English you might say, 'I want to query the Mongo database using Mongoose in a nodejs app...'.

Answer (score 22):

There are no 'joins' in Mongo.  But what you would do is change your User Schema to store the ObjectId's of the Comment and Post documents in an array of your User.  Then use 'populate' when you need the data with the user.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({  
    nick_name:{type:String},  
    email: {  
        type: String,  
        trim: true,  
        required: '{PATH} is required!',
        index: true,
    },
    comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Comment' }],
    posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Post' }]
}, {timestamps: true});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Your query would then look something like this:

```
User.find()
    .populate('comments posts') // multiple path names in one requires mongoose >= 3.6
    .exec(function(err, usersDocuments) {
        // handle err
        // usersDocuments formatted as desired
    });
```

[Mongoose populate docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: The problem with this approach is the growing array, you don't know how much your array of comments or posts are going to grow, that inserts another kind of probems

Comment: The stored array contains only ObjectId's.  Unless I'm missing something, this should scale okay.  If I'm missing something @shontauro, please let me know.

Comment: There is a typo in the second ObjectId. It can generate a runtime error.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Fixed.

Comment: Technically this is correct. But functional point of view, the user should be a stand alone entity and should not have any other information in it. So, all the other entities (where ever the user id needed) should store the user id as one of the field. May be the user can write a view to get comments and posts from multiple collections.

Comment: Yes, Technically, based on the question that was asked.

Knowing the full-use case could change whether or not it should be done.  Having the comments on the user allows for a speed performance and population convenience, a benefit of using NoSQL.  If it were me, I may have a limit on the amount of comment ids stored directly on the user (`recentComments`, by date or number).  Regardless, this doesn't change the `Comment Documents`, they can still be indexed/queried by user id.

If you want all the data unlinked, sounds like you just want a SQL database.

Answer (score 19):

It is possible .you should use **aggregation**.
it should work.
**Initiate the variable**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var userCollection = require('./user');//import user model file
    var resources = {
    nick_name: "$nick_name",
    email: "$email"};

    userCollection.aggregate([{
            $group: resources
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Comments", // collection to join
                localField: "_id",//field from the input documents
                foreignField: "user_id",//field from the documents of the "from" collection
                as: "comments"// output array field
            }
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Post", // from collection name
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "user_id",
                as: "posts"
            }
        }],function (error, data) {
         return res.json(data);
     //handle error case also
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible, you just have to use populate, let me tell you how:

Import your schemas

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSch = require('userSchema');
var postSch = require('postSchema');
var commSch = require('commentSchema');
```

Init all the necessary vars

```
var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSch);
var postModel = mongoose.model('Post', postSch);
var commModel = mongoose.model('Comment', commSch);
```

And now, do the query

```
postModel.find({}).populate('User')
    .exec(function (error, result) {
        return callback(null, null);
    });

commModel.find({}).populate('User')
    .exec(function (error, result) {
        return callback(null, null);
    });
```

This way you get the user inside of your comment and your post, to get the post and comments inside of your user, you have to do 3 queries, one for the user, one for the comments and one for the post, and mix all together

Comment: Thanks for answer but  I want only one query in user collection

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using populate virtual with both comments and posts like docs (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) in model User. And using like this:
`User.find({filter}).populates('virtualComments').populate('virtualPosts')`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29983760)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answers above: **What if we only want a few specific fields returned for the populated documents?** This can be accomplished by passing the usual field name syntax as the second argument to the populate method:

```
Story.
  findOne({ title: /casino royale/i }).
  populate('author', 'name'). // only return the Persons name
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
    // prints "The author is Ian Fleming"

    console.log('The authors age is %s', story.author.age);
    // prints "The authors age is null"
  });
```

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate to do your work in a single query which is almost like a join.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userModel = require('./user');//import user model file
let result = await userModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id),//pass the user id
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",//your schema name from mongoDB
      localField: "_id", //user_id from user(main) model
      foreignField: "user_id",//user_id from user(sub) model
      pipeline: [ 
        {
          $project:{ //use to select the fileds you want to select
            comment:1, //:1 will select the field
            is_active :1,
            _id:0,//:0 will not select the field
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "comments",//result var name
    }
  },
   {
    $lookup: {
      from: "post",//your schema name from mongoDB
      localField: "_id", //user_id from user(main) model
      foreignField: "user_id",//user_id from user(sub) model
       pipeline: [
        {
          $project:{//use to select the fileds you want to select
            post:1,//:1 will select the field
            is_active :1,
              _id:0,//:0 will not select the field
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "posts",//result var name
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{//use to select the fileds you want to select
      nick_name:1,//:1 will select the field
      email:1,
      _id:0,//:0 will not select the field
      comments:1,
      posts:1
    }
  }
])
```