# How to query and get documents from two collections on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to query documents from two collections together on mongoose.
I am familiar with SQL query and but not familiar with mongoDB.
I have two schema for Users, Messages like following.

**Users**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {type: String, unique: true},
    password: String,
    avatar: {type: String, default: ""},
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**Messages**

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    message: { type: String, default: "" },
    from: { type: String, default: "" },
    to: { type: String: default: "" },
    is_read: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    channel: { type: String, default: ''},
    created_at: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
```

I need to get messages with "is_read" is "false".
I want to get "user name" and "avatar" together.
The "from" value of message should be matched with "_id" of User.

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post sums it up well: [Mongoose - query to get data from multiple collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795480/mongoose-query-to-get-data-from-multiple-collections)

Specifically the second upvoted answer mentions similarities between sql and mongodb, and goes on to explain how to link collections in mongoose queries.